# Avoid populating Extended Properties in WCF data contracts

Tags: wcf, datacontract, extended-properties

***How could I avoid populating the ExtendedProperties collection in my data contract?***

My WCF service  is building the data contract from a XML and populating the `ExtendedProperties` with the properties that are not in the contract. Then they are returned and I would like to avoid that.

Clearing the `ExtendedProperties` collections is the straightforward approach but I was looking for a more elegant way to do that.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using one of the other DataContractSerializer constructors that accept a boolean parameter named ignoreExtensionDataObject is the best way I have found to accomplish that.

```
public DataContractSerializer(Type type, 
    IEnumerable<Type> knownTypes, 
    int maxItemsInObjectGraph, 
    bool ignoreExtensionDataObject, 
    bool preserveObjectReferences, 
    IDataContractSurrogate dataContractSurrogate);
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN [Forward-Compatible Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

The round-tripping feature may be turned off, either by setting ignoreExtensionDataObject to true in the DataContractSerializer constructor or by setting the [IgnoreExtensionDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.ignoreextensiondataobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to true on the ServiceBehaviorAttribute. When this feature is off, the deserializer will not populate the ExtensionData property, and the serializer will not emit the contents of the property.